# Php thumbnails on the fly

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd, thumbnails

I have read several different threads regarding this but all of them deal with images that are already on the server.

I am storing images in a database (dont ask why :P) and what I am trying to do is generate the thumb as soon as I upload the pic and before I send it to the database.

I already have GD installed and have also installed timthumb.

Any ideas how this can be done? Or at least how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPThumb has been very easy to work with in my experience: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

About your particular problem: PHP holds the uploaded files temporarily, so you can create a thumbnail from them before the typical `move_uploaded_file` call. After that, call `show(true)` [(this enables the raw data stream on PHPThumb)](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/blob/master/src/GdThumb.inc.php#L954) and store the returned value in your database.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm lost..Can you explain it in a bit more detail please? Atm I am using fread() to read the file and then use addslashes to escape any "illegal" chars. Is 'temp_name' the temporary name that is used by php?

Comment: You have two parts here: the first is creating the thumb, the second is storing it in DB. For the second, I recommend `file_get_contents` in a `BLOB` field, but that should be at your discretion. For the first, it's fairly simple: using PHPThumb, you'd do something like this: create a thumb using `tmp_name`, call PHPThumb's `show(true)` along with `getImageAsString()` and insert the returned value in your DB.